# Keras Signal Processing Model

Tags: python, keras, regression, signal-processing

Heyo, I have a model problem for some signal processing.

Context: I have some signals stored in numpy arrays as floats, they are all of different lengths and I need to extract the offset of the signal at a particular spot in time, the thing is I don't know where that spot is in the array so I cannot resize the array (so that all of the signals have the same length).

I have around 8000 signals with the offset known. So I want to train the model on them.

What I have at the moment

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(None,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="tanh"))
adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam,metrics=['mse', 'acc'])
```

- input_shape=(None,1) as I don't know the length of the array
- activation="tanh" the last layer must be something that can return negative as well.

Basically my model should not be length dependent, should output negative and positive values. This model does not work for what I need and I was wondering if someone can point me into a better direction.

"Doesn't work" as in after 1000 epochs of training of ~ 200 signals/batch, with 100 steps/ epoch, the output was "random" and very far from the real value.

I was thinking of using a ConvNet instead of LSTM. But I cannot use 'Flatten' or 'Reshape'.

One signal with numpy savetxt

```
-1.118700742721557617e+00
-9.661099910736083984e-01
-9.661099910736083984e-01
-1.088183045387268066e+00
-1.149218797683715820e+00
-1.118700742721557617e+00
-1.088183045387268066e+00
-1.118700742721557617e+00
-1.149218797683715820e+00
-1.088183045387268066e+00
-1.088183045387268066e+00
-1.118700742721557617e+00
-1.179736852645874023e+00
-1.149218797683715820e+00
-1.118700742721557617e+00
-1.149218797683715820e+00
-1.240772962570190430e+00
-1.301809072494506836e+00
-1.240772962570190430e+00
-1.179736852645874023e+00
-1.149218797683715820e+00
-1.240772962570190430e+00
-1.332327008247375488e+00
-1.393362998962402344e+00
-1.362845063209533691e+00
-1.271291017532348633e+00
-1.240772962570190430e+00
-1.362845063209533691e+00
-1.423881053924560547e+00
-1.301809072494506836e+00
-1.088183045387268066e+00
-1.027147054672241211e+00
-1.118700742721557617e+00
-1.240772962570190430e+00
-1.332327008247375488e+00
-1.393362998962402344e+00
-1.332327008247375488e+00
-1.301809072494506836e+00
-1.271291017532348633e+00
-1.210254907608032227e+00
-1.057664990425109863e+00
-9.966289997100830078e-01
-9.966289997100830078e-01
-8.440380096435546875e-01
-5.083401203155517578e-01
-3.252310752868652344e-01
-4.778220653533935547e-01
-7.219660282135009766e-01
-7.219660282135009766e-01
-6.609300374984741211e-01
```

Comment: I don't understand your signal form. How does model not work? Can you give some sample data and errors?

Comment: "Doesn't work" as in, after 1000 epochs of training of ~ 200 signals/batch, with 100 steps/ epoch, the output was "random" and very far from the real value.

Comment: How long (in number of samples) is the signature of the thing you want do detect? You should define a model that has a slightly wider receptive field than that, then train on frames sized by the receptive field. Training data must be split into such chucks, and labeled individually (can be done automatically from your input data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure "why" you consider the model "not working". If it's because of metrics, ok, maybe you could increase the number of layers, make it more powerful/complex.

But if the reason is another, please specify it in the question.

You can build a convolutional model using `GlobalMaxPooling2D` or `GlobalAveragePooling2D` instead of `Flatten` or `Reshape`.

One very interesting thing you can do in any model (including the LSTM model) is to add data for the current position.

For instance, if your signal has length 3: `[s0, s1, s2]`, you can add the current location of each step passing input data with shape `(None,2)` like: `[[s0,0],[s1,1],[s2,2]]`

With this, you will help your model to have absolute and relative positions explicitly without depending on very long processing.